# ASP Classic - String replace function fails

Tags: asp-classic

On a development server running IIS 7.5 the following ASP Classic code works as expected.

```
s = "mystring'";
s = s.replace("'","''");
Response.Write(s);
```

Running the same code on a production server (same version of IIS - 7.5) the above code fails, the value of variable s is always blank. No error is displayed, just value of the variable is lost.

Comment: if it is only with the "'" it could be a codepage-issue. Do you read "mystring" out of a textfile?

Comment: No, fails with any type of string replace regardless of characters. The mystring value is just hard coded and is not read from a text file.

Comment: How you know for sure value is blank? Do you have more code around those three lines?

Comment: The output has a length of 0 rather than the expected length of 10...

Comment: OK, can you put one more `Response.Write("test123")` below that code and tell me what is the output. Do you get `test123` in the output or still get 0 data?

Comment: @bluenose1970 That code by itself can't possibly cause what you describe, something else is going on. First debug step I would try is giving different name to the variable. Second step, try to `Response.Write("something")` as previous comment already suggested. When you reply to comments please use `@` to notify like I did now.

Comment: Taking a wild guess here, maybe the default language on the dev server is JScript and on the prod it's VBScript.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yeah that's what I thought - and probably the `Script Error Message` is set to empty string.

Comment: @YK1 yep. Let's wait for Mr. nose here to confirm.

Comment: @bluenose1970 Did you find any solution? I'am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me it has been a CODEPAGE issue. The page that included the ASP file that did the String Replace had CODEPAGE=65001. I changed it to 1252 and now it works correctly.